# What causes a misplaced item error in rebol?

Tags: user-interface, rebol, rebol2

Here is the code pruned down to a minimum to show the error:

```
Rebol []

view center-face layout [
    fld1: field
    fld2: field
    flds: [fld1 fld2]
]
```

Comment: BTW, if you have more questions, once you hit 20 points you can ask in the Rebol and Red chat room here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red

Comment: @johnorork And now... you have the 20 points!  Come say hi.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the shortest example to show the error:

```
layout [ test: []] 
>>Misplaced item: []
```

Rebol uses a number of different dialects, and the two you are using in this example are the **do dialect** and the **view dialect**.  Now inside the 'layout function, you can only have the **view dialect** but you have mixed the two.  So, the parser used by the 'layout function complains of the *misplaced item*.  The dialect expects to see after *flds:* one of the faces such as field, area, label etc but instead finds a block.

Regarding your clarification comment, if you wish to create a block of fields, you can just create the block first and then provide it to the 'layout function like this so that you end up with fields named var1 to var9.

```
lo: [ across ]

for i 1 9 1 [
    repend lo [ 'label  form join "var" i to set-word! join "var" i 'field 'return ]   
]

view layout lo
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks. I am trying to create a block of fields that I can test in a foreach loop. If i try to load up the block outside of the view block it probably wont see those fields. So is there any way to do what I want here?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do so I just expanded my answer to show how to create the layout block programmatically.